# Selecting data and joining fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is "categories" and "foods".

The categories table has two main filds:

- category_id
- category_slug

The "category_slug" is the value for friendly urls.

The foods table I have a field called "category_id" which is filled with the category id.

What happens is that, as I'm working with friendly urls, I don't have the id of the category, I only have the slug.

What I need to do is: Convert "slug" by "id" and look at the table foods and get all the food in that category.

It's a little hard to explain, but I think you understood.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foods` (
  `food_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `food_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`food_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple inner join:

```
SELECT food_name
FROM foods 
JOIN categories
USING (category_id)
WHERE category_slug = :slug
```